# MySQL Backend and MS Access Frontend Where do Queries run

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have a split MS Access application with a MS Access frontend and a MS Access backend running in the client's virtual desktop environment.  All and all it works but some update queries result in Error 3035 "System Resource Exceeded". I believe this is happening due to the VM environment not able to scale memory fast enough when the application is running. (Yes I have confirmed all recordsets are closing and set to nothing).

I have thought about migrating to a MySQL database backend on their web server.

If I do this, where are the queries run; on the MS Access in the VM or on the web server with the backend?

For the record the application is only available to myself (designer) and the single worker charged with using it.  The largest table has more than 110K records.  Also this is more of a data storage application not really a transactional database. Sort of like a data warehouse.

Comment: Also note that this clearly is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you want us to help you with your error 3035, you should ask that. Usually, the query can be adjusted to strain the system less, or can be executed non-transactionally, reducing the need to cache the result.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth my question was not a duplicate but your suggested read is good. From what I gather running queries in Jet vs MySQL depends. I have more research to do because I am not fluent in MySQL dialect as the suggested article points out.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I never through about query transaction setting. I will have to go back and look at that. Good idea.

Comment: Well, please explain why your question isn't a duplicate. The answer on that other post clearly explains where your queries run, and how it is dependent on the type of query. It isn't dependent on if you use Oracle or MySQL

Comment: Ok, it's a duplicate. So what do I do now?

Comment: You can accept the duplicate, or if you already rejected it, you can wait for others to mark the question as a duplicate. Or you can just close the question.